# Bounding probability measure on arbitrary but finite intervals

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-limit-theorems

Let $\mu$ be a probability measure supported on $\mathbb R$.

My question is the following:

> For a given $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$, does there exist a finite number $F > 0$ such that $\mu([-F, F]) >= 1-\epsilon$ holds? In other words, does a probability measure assign 'almost all of the mass' to a finite interval always?

If the answer is 'no', then do we have a name for the measures that indeed satisfy this?

Comment: Yes there does exist such number $F$. In the setting you are operating, you can use monotone convergence. Consider $g_n=\mathbb{1}_{[-n,n]}$. This sequence is monotone non decreasing and converges  to $\mathbb{1}$ pointwise. Also $\mathbb{1}\in L_1(\mu)$ for  $\int\mathbb{1}d\mu=\mu(\mathbb{R})=1$. Then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int g_nd\mu=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mu([-n,n])=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes since $\{[-F;F] \}_{F \in \Bbb N }$ are an increasing sequence of intervals hence $$\lim_{F \to \infty} \mu ( [-F; F]) = \mu ( \lim_{F \to \infty}  [-F; F] ) = \mu ( \Bbb R ) = 1$$